# Finding Frequencies from Log Indexed FFT

Tags: fft, frequency

[image]

I have FFT data that has logarithmically scaled at x-axis as shown on the image. But the problem is I do have only array of float numbers that has 1024 element in it, but I know that is already not a linearly indexed, and I just want to find the corresponding frequencies from array indices.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "log-spaced FFT". You need to be more specific about what that data is and how exactly it was generated.

Comment: There is no such thing as a log-space FFT. You may receive some interpolated result or something else entirely, and it's up to whoever is giving it to you to provide the corresponding frequency axis.

Comment: Let me fix it then. When one plot the FFT, either can plot on the linearly spaced x-axis or logarithmically spaced x-axis to neglect the high frequencies. I am getting the data from Blender - Animation Node add-on's - Sound Spectrum node as a float list. And I've realized that the node's output is already logspaced indicies, not linear. Probably for visualization reasons. My frequency outputs cumulated around  14k to 19k, but the spectrum shows that they should be in 5k to 15k span. So I am getting logspaced indices.

Comment: Hmm... could Logarithmic Fourier transformation be used for this? (LFT) https://homepages.dias.ie/~ajones/publications/28.pdf , 
(FFTLog) https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/FFTLog/

Comment: Sorry for the earlier inconvenient question. I fixed it as clearly as possible.

Comment: What does the Blender API documentation say ? Can you link it ?

Comment: Animation Node is a external product. [link](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/blob/1bbcdcee2081310e6e709015b3557eba176c0d18/animation_nodes/data_structures/sounds/sound.py#L27) here is the source code, if you interested in. My point is there is 22050 total Hz and they fit into 1024 nfft with logaritmic scale not the linear, if it was linear let say I have a spike at 314th point which is 44100 / 1024 * 314 = 13522Hz approx.  if it is linear this approach is correct but log scaled there is a shift in the corresponding freq.

Comment: This looks a lot like Audacity. My recollection of that tool is that it uses a run of the mill FFT, so the data was linearly spaced when exported.  It gives you the option to plot it on a logarithmic axis, but it was the same data.

Comment: @DanSzabo yep, this is Audacity, I've just put the pic as an example of logarithmic scale. But I have a  length 1024 1D array version of it as a data, nothing else, not a GUI.

Comment: @merkwur. The linked method computes a good old fashioned FFT, more/less. It pads it to the nearest power of 2 for some reason, windows the input signal. It is also is doing a real only FFT, so the bin to frequency relationship is a factor of 2 different (someone might check me on that, never done it myself).

Comment: Do you have example data available?

Comment: Do you want me to give you .blender file? @Juha P

Comment: @merkwur - not whole .blender file but just that FFT export data would be helpful so one could load the data into spreadsheet for comparison ... .

Comment: @JuhaP There is two selection in the dropdown menu where I could get the FFT data, one is exponential, one is full. Full is linear. Exponential is; frequencies are fitted in exponential curves, indexing is log, so that, lower frequencies have wider span in x-axis [see doc](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/sound/sound_spectrum/#exponential) and [source code](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/blob/1bbcdcee2081310e6e709015b3557eba176c0d18/animation_nodes/nodes/sound/sound_spectrum.py#L96) here.There will be issues bc the exponential rate if I gave it as plain

Answer (score 1):

This is a question on fitting an exponential through two points, like

[image]

That depends on the parent function, which could take on form of:

$$
f(x) = ab^x \tag{1}
$$

or

$$
f(x) = a b_0^x + c \tag{2}
$$
where $a, b, c$ are parameters that depend on start and end points, $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$, and $b_0$ is chosen. Answer for [1](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ybczeirlox), for [2](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fkwr24p9mi), and [derivations](https://overlordgolddragon.github.io/test-signals/#signal-general-forms-derivations). I don't know which form LFT takes (see @JuhaP's references), it could be either depending on need.

---

#### Example

Suppose frequencies are dyadically distributed (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8,...). Pick $(2)$ with $b_0=2$.  Then, if min and max frequencies are $5\text{Hz}$ and $15k\text{Hz}$, and we have 1024 elements, set

$$
(x_0, y_0) = (0, 5); (x_1, y_1)=(1, 15000)
$$

and round the output, which gives log-spaced frequencies. The $0$ and $1$ is somewhat arbitrary, see code.

[image]

---

#### Validating

If you have access to the transform, you can confirm the resulting frequencies are correct by taking the transform of exactly one period of a pure cosine at any given frequency, and seeing if the output is a single non-zero value. "Log FFT" is just FFT at log spaced frequencies (or at least that's what it could be, but doesn't change the rest of this answer).

---

#### Code

For 2 below, for 1 [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/0.6.1/ssqueezepy/_test_signals.py#L219).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fit_exp(N, fmin, fmax, tmin=0, tmax=1, b0=2, endpoint=True):
    a = (fmax - fmin) / (b0**tmax - b0**tmin)
    c = (fmin * b0**tmax - fmax * b0**tmin) / (b0**tmax - b0**tmin)
    
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, N, endpoint=endpoint)
    return a*b0**t + c

fmin = 5
fmax = 15000
N = 1024

freqs = np.round(fit_exp(N, fmin, fmax, b0=2))
plt.plot(freqs)
plt.scatter([0, N - 1], [fmin, fmax], color='tab:red')
```

Comment: I feel this is the way I should go with it, but there is something confusing to me because I've consistently asked deficient version of the question. Sorry for that. I have a 44100 Sr and I have 0Hz - 22050Hz freq range fitted in 1024 nfft, let say at 314 point I have a spike and I want to find the corresponding freq, which is if linear spaced;  44100 / 1024 * 314 = 13522Hz approx. but appears to me either I will shifted the all indicies logarithmically then I will replace 314 with corresponding value which is seems to me to prone to mistakes, fitting in the exp is more reliable.

Comment: @merkwur As in general, rounding should delay as long as possible - so yes, exp fit first, then adjust to sampling rate, then round. So `round(freqs[313] * 44100)`, where `freqs` wasn't rounded. From comments under your question it seems it's indeed FFT - just check how log scaling is done and apply one of $(1)$ or $(2)$, it'll be exact.

Comment: Here is the sound spectrum node [doc](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/sound/sound_spectrum/#exponential), here is the [source code](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/blob/1bbcdcee2081310e6e709015b3557eba176c0d18/animation_nodes/nodes/sound/sound_spectrum.py#L96), default rate is 5.

Comment: @merkwur If you have the source code you can perfectly undo the steps. Copy relevant code or breakpoint into it, use toy data, see if `undo(bins)` matches `spectrum`.

Comment: the issue is I am getting the data from the node. I do not have a direct permission to manipulate the source code of the node. Therefore I need to do undo step onto output of the node.